# AWS SDK with Chef 12.5 or greater

Tags: chef-infra, amazon-kms

Process: 
1. Store passwords that are aws-kms encrypted in as default attribute in an array.

2. Unencrypt at runtime with creds that are stored in protected location .aws/creds
3. Set plaintext array back into node array
4. Parse node array in template
5. Discard plaintext passwords

I am trying to reference a node.runstate variable that is set in a custom 
resource in another resource.

Custom Resource:

```
resource_name :secrets_kms

property :password, String, name_property: true
property :region, String, default: 'us-east-1'
property :nodevariable, String
property :path_to_secrets, [String, nil], default: nil

load_current_value do
  if ::File.exist?("/tmp/encryptedpassword")
  password IO.read("/tmp/encryptedpassword")
  end
end

# Setting up the default action to be decrpyt 
action :decrypt do
  file '/tmp/encryptedpassword' do
    content password
    action :create
  end

# Converge only if password is changed
  converge_if_changed :password do

  # Installs Chef Gem aws-sdk
    chef_gem 'aws-sdk' do
      compile_time true
    end

    # Require install aws-sdk
    require 'aws-sdk'

    # Detects platfrom if amazon to use IAM roles vs keys
    if node['platform'] == 'amazon'
      kms = Aws::KMS::Client.new(region: region)
    else
      # Loads secret file and connect using files access_key_id and     secret_access_key provisioned at run time
      creds = YAML.load(::File.read(path_to_secrets))
      kms = Aws::KMS::Client.new(
        region: region,
        access_key_id: creds['access_key_id'],
        secret_access_key: creds['secret_access_key']
      )
    end

    # Decode password into Base64
    value = Base64.strict_decode64(password)
    # Decrypt the encrypted text
    decrypted = kms.decrypt(ciphertext_blob: value)
    node.run_state[:nodevariable] = decrypted.plaintext
  end
end
```

After this custom resource has ran. I would like to have it update the default attribute to the plain text value (which is part of an array), then I would like to pass this variable into a template resource.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I assume you wish to retrieve the `node.run_state[:nodevariable]` elsewhere in your run, but custom resources run in their own run context, and thus the `node.run_state` hash is relative to the custom resource and not to the global context. But there's a bunch of things unclear on your questions. Please [edit] and details what's going wrong.

Comment: No error the value in the other resource i showing up blank

Comment: I have updated my post to be more descriptive @Tensibai

Comment: Move your code into a library module to call it at compile time in recipe, in a custom resource this is likely to be brittle. Maybe coderanger will have a better option, but you'll have a better chance on http://discourse.chef.io or on the slack channel I think. (you can find the link on http://learn.chef.io/community ). Heading to bed.